# how do i get json returned from a form with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP form that displays the results via AJAX. I am able to get results back from PHP as a JSON array and display it. However, there is one part of the form processing thats handled by Javascript, and if there is an error in this part of the form processing, Id like to be able to send back the results like I do with PHP as an array I can parse as AJAX results.

I suck at Javascript, so I havent gotten very far with this yet:

```
var valid = function_to_see_if_address_is_valid();

// if it returns from the function as valid dont do anything just keep going 

if(valid) {


}

// if the address is invalid, send back json to the ajax php script and exit the form processing

else {


  var valid_status = '{"status" : "error"}';
  return valid_status;

}
```

In my head, this should send me back a JSON array, but it doesnt seem to work that way.

UPDATE:

I guess I figured the AJAX part was irrelevant because it works and all I want to do is to know how to send an object/array or whatever back to the original PHP page (ie, the ajax).

But since you seem to all insist on know what the AJAX code is.. here you go, knock yourselves out..

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  $("#withdraw").submit(function(){

    var data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "/form/", 
      data: data,
          success: function(data) { // do stuff with data returned // }
 }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't see how this is a PHP question. If the problem is with JavaScript, please remove the PHP tag.

Comment: You don't appear to have any AJAX in your above code whatsoever.

Comment: I guess I figured the AJAX part was irrelevant because it works and all I want to do is to know how to send an object/array or whatever back to the original PHP page (ie, the ajax).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do with your code snippet, however you can if you wanted to pass data from a JS file to PHP you can use AJAX to do so.

Here's how I've done something similar

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify("your array here"); //turn the array into a json array
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "YOURPHPFILE.php",
  data: {
    jsonString: jsonString //post through the array to YOURPHPFILE.php so you can access it there
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $('body').append(data)
  }
});
```

You can then catch it in the PHP like so

```
myArray = $_REQUEST['jsonString'];
$apiArray = json_decode($myArray, true);
```

I'm not entirely sure how it will fit into your file structure but hopefully it might be of some use.